# Magento 2.3 - $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($product) returning fatal error

Tags: magento2.3, configurable-product-options

I am using the following code in a plugin's `aroundGetItemData()` method.

```
$product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($product)
```

It's returning me the following error,

> Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getName() on null in /vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php:992
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 /generated/code/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/Model/Product/Type/Configurable/Interceptor.php(310):

When I investigated, I found that some of the selected attributes are not valid for this product as the simple products as out of stock.

How to handle this error? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you get data in `$product`?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting data in the product object.

Comment: Open `/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php` file and see in `getOrderOptions` function `$product->getCustomOption('simple_product')` getting or not.